# R-Java error using XLConnect

Tags: java, r

I have trouble with using XLConnect library. I am getting an error for the below code:

```
library(XLConnect)
wb<-loadWorkbook("name.xlsx", create = NULL)
```

And the related error is:

```
Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java):
```

I cant solve this problem. I searched a lot of topics. However, I couldn't manage to solve.

I use RStudio as gui. The version are as below:

```
R                : [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5
RStudio          : Version 1.0.136
Java             : Version 8 Update 121 (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Windows          : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
```

I will be very glad for any help or suggestion.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you attempting with `..., create = NULL)`. I see no description in the help page for what should be expected with that parameter.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing "......., create=TRUE)". Thanks a lot the comment. The comment showed me the way.